# Obtain Key from value in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I have a JS Object with boolean values only as follows

```
var obj = {
    key_1: false,
    key_2: true,
    key_3: false
}
```

I know that only one of the values can be true. Is there a library method for the same because I can't find any.

I tried using `_.indexOf` but that did not seem to work

Comment: Pliantly of options to choose from, `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, `Object.entries`, `for key in obj`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know there is only one `true` value you can use `find()` on `Object.keys()` to return key of that value.

```js
var obj = {
  key_1: false,
  key_2: true,
  key_3: false
}

var key = Object.keys(obj).find(e => obj[e] == true);
console.log(key)
```

Comment: You don't have to check if `obj[e]` is true, you can just return it

Answer (score 0):

Other solution that won't go outside of it's own scope. Makes it more "pure"
(less browser support)

```js
var obj = {
  key_1: false,
  key_2: true,
  key_3: false
}

var key = Object.entries(obj).find(a => a[1])[0]
console.log(key)
```